# Prevent Inserting Duplicate Record in a Database When Refresh Form

Tags: vb.net, c#-4.0

I have small project which has one form and that form contain 5 text-boxes. When I click on the submit button a new entry added in grid-view.

It works fine but the problem is that when I refresh the page manually double entry made into the database with same data. How to prevent this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You should provide the that makes entry to the database. It will be also useful when you specify the events and what controls used in the form etc.,

Comment: As I believe Sivaraman meant can you please show some code.

Comment: Without code, it's REALLY hard to help you in any real way, but maybe just look at the `Contains` function... If the gridview already contains the record, then exit the sub... Again, without more code, it's impossible to really help here...